# Nested while loop won't ask to run program again correctly

Tags: java, output, nested-loops

Well I have this hw problem where I have to use only nested while loops no do whiles at all.So basically I have the code down, but it wont run parts of the loop it keeps saying yes or no. Its suppose to go like this

Guess the secret number.

Enter maximum value for secret number: 10

A new secret number has been chosen.

Enter guess: 3

Too low; try again.

Enter guess: 8

Too low; try again.

Enter guess: 9

Too low; try again.

Enter guess: 10

You won in 4 guesses!

Play again? (Y/N) y

A new secret number has been chosen.

Enter guess: 7

Too high; try again.

Enter guess: 3 Too low; try again.

Enter guess: 5

You won in 3 guesses!

Play again? (Y/N) n

```
 public static void main(String arg[])
{
    int guess = 0,max,guesses = 0;
    String response;
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Guess the secret number\n");
    System.out.println("Enter maximum value for secret number: ");
    max=input.nextInt();
    int numbers=(int) (Math.random()* max) + 1;
    while(true) 
    {
        System.out.println("A new secret number has been chosen.");

        while (guess!=numbers)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter guess");
            guess=input.nextInt();
            guesses++;

            if (guess<numbers)
            {
                System.out.println("Two low; Try again ");
            }
            else if (guess>numbers)
            {
                System.out.println("To high; Try again");
            }

        }
        System.out.println("You won in " + guesses + "!"); 
        System.out.print("\nPlay again? (Y/N)"); 
        response = input.next(); 
        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        {
            continue; 
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }

    }
    input.close();
}
```

(this is what I get )

Enter maximum value for secret number: 
  5

A new secret number has been chosen.

Enter guess
4

To high; Try again

Enter guess
3

You won in 2!

Play again? (Y/N)y

A new secret number has been chosen.

You won in 2!

Play again? (Y/N)y

A new secret number has been chosen.

You won in 2!

Play again? (Y/N)

(so the loop won't call in to guess again)

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinitialize **guess** and **numbers** to start a new round of the game.

Move these two lines down, inside the outer **while** loop:

```
int numbers=(int) (Math.random()* max) + 1;
int guess = 0, guesses = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close, but you need to reset your important values after each time you win. You can do this by simply moving them into your outer nest loop so that each time the inner loop breaks, they get reset to what you want them to be before each round of the guessing game. See here:

```
 public static void main(String arg[])
{
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

    while(true) 
    {
        int guess = 0,max,guesses = 0;
        String response;
        System.out.println("Guess the secret number\n");
        System.out.println("Enter maximum value for secret number: ");
        max=input.nextInt();
        int numbers=(int) (Math.random()* max) + 1;
        System.out.println("A new secret number has been choosen.");

        while (guess!=numbers)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter guess");
            guess=input.nextInt();
            guesses++;

            if (guess<numbers)
            {
                System.out.println("Two low; Try again ");
            }
            else if (guess>numbers)
            {
                System.out.println("To high; Try again");
            }

        }
        System.out.println("You won in " + guesses + "!"); 
        System.out.print("\nPlay again? (Y/N)"); 
        response = input.next(); 
        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        {
            continue; 
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }

    }
    input.close();
}
```